# Simplifying a document library page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, document-library

For the following document library can I delete the controls in the box?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on Edi Page and then Edit web part. You can rid of **new document** link by chaging ToolbarType to **No Toolbar** in List Views. The search box can be removed by going to  Miscellaneous section and unchecking **Display search box option**. All Documents link will remain though. You may need to do some css tweaking for hiding that.

Comment: +1 thank you. Works fine and now looks a lot cleaner. Do you know the `css` tweaking required?

Comment: Unfortunately not at this time.

Answer (score 7):

1.Add that Document Library as WebPart

2.Than Edit Web Part

3.In Properties List View, Select Toolbar Type As "No Toolbar"

Answer (score 2):

To remove the both of the links for One library I would suggest :
Open that page in firefox. Using firebug find out the class in which you can add `css` like `Display:"none"`
Edit page (AllItem.aspx)
Add WebPart (Media and Content) => (Content Editor) => Edit Source 
In this add Style tag copy `css` and done. Links will be not visible for that list.

E.g. In my case I found using firebug 2 classes and I added them in Content Editor web part.

```
<style type="text/css">

.ms-list-addnew-aligntop {
    display: none !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
.ms-csrlistview-controldiv {
    display: none !important;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
</style>
```

This worked for me.